# How do I proceed with this trigonometric integral $∫\sec^3θ\cot θ\; dθ$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I tried to perform trig sub on the equation below and what I got was
$$∫\sec^3θ\cot θ\; dθ$$
I'm not sure if this is correct and I'm also really not sure how to proceed from here.

$$\int{{\sqrt{\ln^2 x+1}\over{x\ln{x}}}\; dx}$$

[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSS8Q.png)

Comment: Maybe you can tell us which one of the trig substitutions you tried, what you found for $d \theta$.

Comment: @BernardMassé He has written his attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\int \sec^3t\cdot\cot  t\ dt=\int\dfrac{dt}{\sin t\cos^2t}=\int\dfrac{\sin t\ dt}{(1-\cos^2t)\cos^2t}$$

Set $\cos t=u$  then $$\int\dfrac{du}{(1-u^2)u^2}=\int\dfrac{1-u^2+u^2}{(1-u^2)u^2}du=\int\dfrac{du}{u^2}+\dfrac12\int\dfrac{1-u+1+u}{(1-u^2)}\ du$$

Comment: Thank you for this. Though I just want to clarify if the $sin t$ on the numerator is because you multiplied the equation by $sin t/sin t$ to obtain a $ sin^2 t$ on the denominator

Comment: @Holyyy, You are right

Answer (score 1):

Note

\begin{align}
\int \sec^3t\cot  t\ dt
&= \int \frac{\sec t}{\tan t} (1+\tan^2t)dt
= \int \left(\frac1{\sin x} + \sec t \tan t\right)dt\\
&=\ln\tan \frac t2 + \sec t+C
\end{align}